# Performance issues with large table in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

As a learning exercise, I've been adapting an existing, working web application to use Vue.js (it's a technology I'm interested in for another project). I'm just wondering whether there are some tips and tricks I need to know about as regards handling large tables (of e.g. 1000-1500 rows).

In my existing web application, I simply loop through the Javascript array of products, building the HTML for the table body by string concatenation and then inserting it into the empty table via JQuery. This works fine in performance terms, although of course it looks a little messy and maintainability isn't great.

For my Vue.js version, I instead used a template block, i.e:

```
<template v-for="product in productList">
```

The resultant HTML appears to be identical. But for some reason or other, the Vue.js version is a little sluggish in response. For example, when I click on a select in one of the product rows, it takes half a second or so for the options to appear, and having selected one, there is a similar delay in updating the row class.

For various reasons it's impractical for me to be able to put the actual source code for this up on something like Fiddle, although I'm trying to create a simplified reproducible example. I was just wondering, though, what the difference might be between a Vue-managed table and a straight HTML one, such that I might be able to home in on what's causing this unexpected sluggishness.

Oh, and in case you're thinking it's a bad idea to have tables of this many rows, this is for an in-house web application, with known, tested clients, and the performance of the pure HTML version is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is a drawback with `Vue` and MVVM libraries in general. What `Vue` actually does is create a new Vue instance for each item in the loop and bind it to data which slows down rendering but speeds up updates. Unfortunately, there appears to be no way to make `v-for` faster, so you have to work around it, see this issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2000

Comment: OK, that makes sense. For this table, I don't actually need the interactivity that Vue allows, I was really just using it to simplify and clean up the code, effectively just using it like Mustache templating. I suppose I could actually just use Mustache for this instead (unless that introduces other issues)?

Comment: I'd suggest a virtual scroller for this. I came across this clear implementation of it and threw some form inputs in there to see how it behaves. It feels good with even 100,000 items: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/ftek781b/4/

Comment: That looks good, and it's something I would consider if I _needed_ to use Vue for this table. As I mentioned, though, the performance of a straight HTML table is fine and doesn't require this kind of technique, so it's not the large table per se which is the problem.

Comment: What I've actually done is used a Handlebars template here instead of Vue, and it works well and has given me the snappy performance back. Given that Vue has Mustache/Handlebars style templating, it would be handy if it had a mode in which it could be used as a simple replacement for those templating engines, without the reactivity (which is clearly what's slowing it down here). Maybe it can and I'm just missing it?

Comment: You can try `stateless` component which has no data or this, just render the template

Comment: @tomwang1013 can you elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

For my case I just had to delay my columns render a bit and performances **hugely** increased.

Let's say you're doing a `v-for` on `columns: [...]`, just create a `displayedColumns: []`  that will replace it and in `mounted` add

```js
this.columns.forEach((c, i) =>
  setTimeout(() => this.displayedColumns.push(c), i * 200),
)
```

It's better to do an async sleep for each iteration rather than creating severals timeout but you got the idea.